# How to get the ID of all the checked boxes on displayed data base QUICKFIX?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

I have displayed a table of my data from the data base with check boxes to the left. I want to find a way to link the check boxes to the question number (ID).  when I hit submit I want the selected id's  to be echoed. pretty much I want someone to be able to select the questions they want and then display them.

```
  <?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("####","####","#####","###");

   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM q_and_a ");

 echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
<th>Add</th>
<th>#</th>
<th>Question</th>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
<th>D</th>
<th>Answer</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo "<tr>";

echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="questions[]" value="$id"></td>';

echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['question'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['choiceA'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['choiceB'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['choiceC'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['choiceD'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['answer'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

submit button

```
<form  method="POST" action="makeTest.php">
<input type="submit" name="make" value="Make Test">
</form>
```

Comment: just check some values and submit the form, access the values thru `$_POST['questions']`

Comment: for `POST` the input fields should be in the `form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Make some  edits to your code then it will work.
1. Change your query by adding fields not * (to ensure performance and display order)

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,question,choiceA,choiceB,choiceC,choiceD,answer FROM q_and_a ");
```

2. then before while block open form tag(HTML)

   ```
   <?php 
    //above codes will be there as you show before 
   echo '<form  method="POST" action="makeTest.php">';
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   { $id=$row['id'];  // initialize your id here, so as to pass it in checkbox too
    // then continue with your code
   }
   ?>
   <input type="submit" name="make" value="Make Test">
   </form>
   ```

in maketest.php yo can hande ckeckbox using  foreach, see below

```
    foreach($_POST['questions'] as $questions){
                          //do your job

    }
```

Comment: this works more efficiently but it always says the id is at 4.  how u show me how to print which ids are clicked when i hit make test. i click make with 2 selected and it gives me back 2 4's

Comment: I think i don't understand what you want pal

Comment: after the for loop excecutes the id is stuck at 4 so its only out putting 4s. rather then a 1 two three or four. i think u didnt test ur code so u obviously dont know what ur doing.